# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb even I have installed it - Python 3.4.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, mysql-python

I have `Python 3.4.5 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)` on Windows 10 64 Bit.

I have installed

```
pip install mysqlclient
pip install mysql-python
```

I have `import MySQLdb` in my code and it says `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb`

Why am I getting this error even when I have installed it?

Some posts says `MySQLdb` is not available for Python 3.x but I have CentOS server with Python 3.4.5 and its working 100% perfect there.

Comment: There are often installation problems with this connector. You may consider using [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/8.0.6) which is written in Python and don’t really on the C library. This connector is officially supported by [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/).

Answer (score 1):

Note: MySqlDb is known as MySQL-python on the PyPi repository (they changed its name).

On Windows, you only have the 32 bits version of MySQL-python available on PyPi. You can install it but it won’t work on you 64 bits system (unless you install a 32 bits version of MySQL + MySQL Client + Python). Ie.: all your toolchain must use the same architecture.

On Linux, the library is built from the source.

Notice you can meet the same problem on Windows with Apache + mod_wsgi + Python. You need to choose between 32 bits and 64 bits. You cannot mix it.

My recommendation is to use [MySQL-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/8.0.6) instead.

**edit**

A 64 bits version of MySQL-python is available on the non-official but popular website of [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python).

Comment: Does MySQL-connector-python have same code usage? because I have a very big project that I want to clone in my localhost and I dont want to change all MySQL related code in that project.

Comment: The connection URL change slightly.

Comment: it has manylinux and macos versions for python3.4, will those work for me? they dont have win version for python3.4

Comment: Use pip install. And try it on your virtualenv.

Comment: Hey, I did `pip install MySQL-python` in my conda envirement, and I got `Requirement already satisfied: MySQL-python in c:\programdata\anaconda2\envs\python3\lib\site-packages` I still get `ImportError: No module named MySQLdb`

Answer (score -3):

import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()